# How to startup up services on a Docker image?

Tags: php, nginx, docker, dockerfile, php-7

I've created a [Dockerfile](https://bitbucket.org/konato/web/src/8b3c8e6d61d004056068079ad55a4845b6460c04/docker/php7-beta.dockerfile?at=master#php7-beta.dockerfile-50) for a image to run PHP7 on FPM + Nginx, but I can't get the image to start up the services correctly.

How this should be done exactly?

Here's the part where I'm doing it currently:

```
CMD service php7-fpm start; \
    service php7-fpm status; \
    service nginx start; \
    service nginx status
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When managing multiple services you will want to user supervisord.

In your Dockerfile.

```
Additional commands...
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y supervisor
ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf
Additional commands...
CMD ["/bin/supervisord", "-c /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf"]
```

**supervisord.conf**

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:php7]
command=<command to start php7>
autostart=true
autorestart=true
<repeat for additional services>...
```

This will ensure the container doesn't exit once everything is started.  Remember Docker is *supposed* to be a one process environment with that process running in the foreground and not the background as a service.

Comment: boo. seems supervisor is the answer, indeed. but why wouldn't `CMD service nginx start` work?

Comment: as noted above it does not work because Docker expect applications to run in the foreground.  when you start an application as a service it is started in the background and the container exits.  so if you want the container to stay up when you go `docker run -td mycontainer` you need to ensure the service is running in the foreground instead of as a service.   Also, if you just want to run nginx and nothing else you could go: `CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`, noticing again that the process is not daemonized but running in the foreground.

Comment: Got it! I thought by "docker is supposed to be a one process env" you meant it was a convention, not a technical constraint.

Answer (score 2):

you need a process manager, such as supervisor, s6, daemontools, or any other

see the doc for supervisor for example

https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: what's the advantage on using another package such as supervisor instead of built-in System V / upstart jobs, that are a common use case for Nginx/PHP?
Also, is there any reason for that `CMD` not working in the first place?

Comment: The container and image are already gone. The other answer solved the issue and explained it.